# Obtener distancia entre dos puntos declarados en un struct

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos

tengo un struct con diferentes parámetros, entre ellos, uno consistente en un punto de un plano, con una coordenada **x** y otra **y**.

Quiero crear una función que, a partir de dos puntos, calcule su distancia con la fórmula correspondiente. Mi problema es que no consigo enlazar valores para los puntos, y da resultados incoherentes.

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define N 20

struct Tpunto                   // punto en un plano, x abscisas, y ordenadas
{
    float x;
    float y;
};

struct TlistaPuntos            //Lista de puntos del plano
{
    int tam;                      //cantidad de valores en el vector puntos
    struct Tpunto puntos[N];
};

int distancia_puntos(struct Tpunto x, struct Tpunto y);


void main()
{
    struct Tpunto p1, p2;

    printf("\nLa distancia entre los puntos %d y %d es %d", p1, p2, distancia_puntos(p1, p2));

    printf("\n\n");

}

int distancia_puntos(struct Tpunto punto1, struct Tpunto punto2)
{
    int resul=sqrt((pow(punto2.x-punto1.x, 2))+(pow(punto2.y-punto1.y, 2)));

    return resul;
}
```

Comment: Estás interpretando tipos *float* como *int* . Haz que el resultado de `distancia_puntos` sea `float`.

Comment: Ademas, En este ejemplo falta inicializar p1 y p2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No estoy seguro si entiendo del todo tu consulta, pero por lo que puedo concluir tu problema es como asignar valores a las variables del struct. La asignación sería más o menos así:

```
void main()
{
  struct Tpunto p1, p2;
  p1.x = val_1_x // asignar valor para el punto1 en x
  p1.y = val_1_y // asignar valor para el punto1 en y

  p2.x = val_2_x // asignar valor para el punto2 en x
  p2.y = val_2_y // asignar valor para el punto2 en y

  //.. resto del código luego de la asignación
}
```

Además, como mencionan en uno de los comentarios, la función que calcula distancia deberías cambiarla para que retorne un valor `float`. Debería quedar algo como lo siguiente:

```
float distancia_puntos(struct Tpunto punto1, struct Tpunto punto2)
{
  return sqrt((pow(punto2.x-punto1.x, 2))+(pow(punto2.y-punto1.y, 2)));
}
```

Luego esto y almacenado los valores deseados en el struct, tus algoritmos deberían dar valores más coherentes.

Saludos

Comment: Gracias, ese era uno de mis problemas. Sin embargo, ya he asignado valores y siguen apareciendo incoherentes. 

struct Tpunto p1, p2;
    p1.x=5.5;
    p1.y=4.0;
    p2.x=3.3;
    p2.y=2.2;

    printf("\nLa distancia entre los puntos %f y %f es %f", p1, p2, distancia_puntos(p1, p2));

¿Qué tengo mal?

Comment: Podrías comentar cuáles son los valores incoherentes? actualicé mi respuesta con mi sugerencia para la función `distancia_puntos`

Comment: Los valores que aparecen son (dejo la linea de printf): 

La distancia entre los puntos 512.00123 y 3.600001 es 2.842534.

La función funciona correctamente, pero no entiendo por qué los los dos primeros valores no son correctos.

Comment: %f se utiliza para imprimir valores de variables de tipo `float`. Las variables `p1` y `p2` son de tipo `Tpunto` por lo que concluyo que C está interpretando los structs como valores y los está pasando a float. Para imprimir los valores de los puntos deberías hacer algo como: `printf("\nLa distancia entre los puntos (%f,%f) y (%f,%f) es %f", p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y, distancia_puntos(p1, p2));`